# Spyder crashed after multithreading

Tags: crash, reset, anaconda, spyder

I had an attempt at multithreading and it caused Spyder to crash. I tried the following command to reset Spyder and it successfully did that, however Spyder does't run.

```
 python -c "from spyderlib.spyder import main; main()" --reset
```

And when I try to run it again, it gives me the following error AGAIN:[image]

Any idea how to fix this? I'm running Anaconda 32 bit on Windows 7 OS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Uninstalled Anaconda.
- Removed everything from user/.spyder.
- Removed everything spyder related.
- Removed the code that caused the error.
- Reinstalled Anaconda.

  All works fine now.
  Checked on Spyder's GitHub issue but there was no answer for it.

Comment: Likely running `spyder --reset` from the cmd shell as noted in the error would have fixed this too.

Comment: @asmeurer that was exact first thing that I tried and it didn't work.

Comment: I had such problem and spyder --reset fixed all of things and now I can launch Spyder.